# How count initial letter from value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have a table called "customers" in MySQL and with

```
SELECT id, name, left(UPPER(name),1) AS letter
```

get this:

```
id | name   | letter 
 1    John      J 
 2    James     J 
 3    Julia     J 
 4    Lauren    L 
 5    Peter     P 
 6    Pietro    P
```

But now I need to get this counting the total of initial letters

```
id | name   | letter | total 
 1    John      J       3
 2    James     J       3 
 3    Julia     J       3 
 4    Lauren    L       1 
 5    Peter     P       2 
 6    Pietro    P       2
```

I solved it (temporary) adding

```
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customers WHERE left(UPPER(name),1) = letter) AS total"
```

, but my original query include many INNER JOIN, so, this last *Select* duplicates the inner join and *wheres* (maybe unnecesary).

Any suggestions?

Comment: `select count(*), left(name, 1) ... group by left(name, 1)`, basically?

Comment: Yep, with "group by" just show the fist name of every letter (John, Lauren, Peter) but the count is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join your first query with a subquery that gets the counts for each initial.

```
SELECT id, name, letter, total
FROM customers AS c
JOIN (SELECT UPPER(LEFT(name, 1)) AS letter, COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM customers
      GROUP BY letter) AS l
ON l.letter = UPPER(LEFT(c.name, 1))
```

Comment: Hey, that's was so fast! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in an outer select:

```
select id, name, count(*)
from (SELECT id, name, left(UPPER(name),1) AS letter 
        from da_table) as dummy
group by id, name;
```

... where the inner select has your heinous joins.

Whoops - should have read.  Just change the query to only pull "letter" from the inline view, count them and group by "letter".

```
select letter, count(*)
from [all kinds of stuff here) as dummy
group by letter;
```